# Is every homeomorphism approximately a product of homeomorphisms?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, products, homeomorphism

Let $\phi$ be a homeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$, $\epsilon>0$, and $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a non-empty compact.  Does there necessarily exist homeomorphisms $\phi_1,\phi_2$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and on $\mathbb{R}^m$, respectively, such that
$$
\sup_{x \in K}\left\|
\phi(x,y) -(\phi_1(x),\phi_2(y))
\right\|<\epsilon?
$$

In other words, is every homeomorphism on a product space approximately the product of homeomorphisms on its components?

Comment: Let $n=m=1$, $K$ be a unit square, and $\phi(x,y)=(y,x)$. I believe this is then false for $\epsilon<1/2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $m=n=1$, $K=[0, 1]$ and $\phi$ to be rotation by 90 degrees.

Then the $x$-coordinate of $(\phi_1(x), \phi_2(y))$ is bounded for $x\in K$ and any $\phi_1, \phi_2$ while there are points with arbitrarily large $y$-coordinate (which becomes arbitrarily large $x$-coordinate upon applying $\phi$).